# Pass date column in open query view Oracle in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Can anyone please tell me if the below query is correct or Incorrect. In this am trying to run it on SQL Server but the view is created on Oracle database. Especially date column is proper or not. as am not getting any record instead of that getting error

> returned message "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".

```
select *
from openquery(Oracle,'select "bs" from temp.views_employe where "Joining Date">=''2020-06-29 '' ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the date literal syntax `date '2020-06-29'` so

```
select * 
  from openquery(Oracle,
                 'select "bs" from temp.views_employe where "Joining Date">= date ''2020-06-29'' ')
```

You could also use an explicit `to_date`

```
select * 
  from openquery(Oracle,
                 'select "bs" from temp.views_employe where "Joining Date">= to_date( ''2020-06-29'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'' ) ')
```

Comment: Even after doing above changes getting error "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string"

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: @KuwarpratapSingh - Which version are you using?  Is the error coming from the query?  Or from something in the view?  Perhaps the view is incorrectly coded and is doing some additional implicit conversions that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: am using Sql client 2018 , also there is something in view because of that not getting record .. View is in Oracle DB and am running it from Sql client may be that the reasons

Comment: Is there any way to check the issue in view or in Sql client

Comment: can we tag  sql-server to this question, please.

Comment: When you say "Sql client" I'm guessing that you mean SSMS.  There are lots of different SQL clients in the world (just like there are lots of different databases that support SQL not just Microsoft's SQL Server).  Can you post the full error stack?  I haven't looked at what happens when you query an Oracle view that has a syntax error via a linked server.

Comment: @Justin Cave, Right am using SSMS ,getting error "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string"  after executing below script.

Comment: @KuwarpratapSingh What "below script" are you referring to? Two were posted - we can't read your mind or see what you are doing. But step 1 is to write and debug the desired query using oracle tools. Once you have working, you can then attempt to execute it via tsql. Or better yet - ask someone with the appropriate skills at your workplace to help you. It is suspicious you say "pass date column" in your title but your query has a string constant. Did you over-simplify?